# Verification - Matrices and Linear Equations Part 1

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

Would just like to verify my Answers and bounce off my ideas and thinking with someone as I feel quite alone in this course. I am usually great at maths and enjoy it but these matrices and linear equations I really hate. If anyone knows any great websites that are easy learning please post them along with your reply! :)

Here are questions, my answers and thinking.. Please comment and direct me if I have completely missed the mark! Thank you in advance!

Question 1
[image]

I see this as an easy question, Only B is a linear equation as A cannot be as it has square rooted variables as well as cubed variables.

Question 2

[image]

A - False because it is a rectangular matrix and doesn't have a inverse 
B- True as it contains leading 1s that are alone in their columns

Comment: Your answers are correct as well as your reasoning.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! That is encouraging!